# Show that T is a linear transformation and find a basis for kerT.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: P2 -> R2 by T[p(x)]=\begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\p(1)\end{bmatrix}

Show T is a linear transformation. I understand that I have to implant f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y), but have no clue how to do this.

I also do not understand what I am row reducing to get the kernel.

Comment: You don’t need a matrix for $T$. Use the basic definition of its kernel: the set of vectors that are mapped to $0$. The kernel therefore consists of second-degree or lower polynomials that have roots at both $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
What happens to 
$$
\alpha p_1(x)+\beta p_2(x)
$$
under $T$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$?

For the second part,
take $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and force it to be in the kernel, i.e.
$$
p(0)=c=0
$$
and so 
$$
p(1)=0\implies a+b=0\implies b=-a
$$
so $p(x)=a(x^2-x)$, and $\ker(T)=\text{span}\{ x^2-x\}$, and your kernel is one dimensional, as you would expect from rank nullity.